# How to calculate uncompressed gif image size with transparency effect

Tags: image, size, gif, multimedia

- Spatial resolution l024xl024
- Color model: Palette base colors
- Numbers of colors: 256 colors
- transparency: 2 - states of transparency
- frames: 5